# Socket.io taking a long time to disconnect on Heroku

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, heroku

I'm running a Nodejs server allowing users to connect with socket.io. Locally, when the tab or window is closed, the disconnect event is called immediately. However, when done on Heroku the event takes around a minute and a half to be called.

I have read the other similar questions, and they all reference either heartbeat or ping timeout. The most current API I can find is [this](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1), seeming to indicate I should use pingTimeout and pingInterval. My current pingTimeout code is:

```
var Server = require('socket.io');
var io = new Server(http, {pingInterval: 5000, pingTimeout: 10000});
```

And I have tried:

```
var Server = require('socket.io');
var io = new Server(http, {'pingInterval': 5000, 'pingTimeout': 10000});
```

As well. Neither options seem to have any effect on the 1 and a half minute wait time when a user closes the tab.

What can I do to debug this, and is there something simple I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem. I know it's a long time ago, but did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't figure it out, and eventually ended up resorting to a manual ping function, if I remember correctly. Best of luck, though! :)

Answer (score 0):

i am currently using io.set to specify this and it works (socket.io v1.3.7 and node 4x stable). hope this helps

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.set('heartbeat timeout', 50000);
io.set('heartbeat interval', 2000);
```